# What's a good alternative to a hashmap in C?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, parsing, data-structures

I'm trying to parse a file for certain characters (limited to readable ASCII). I want to then print out the characters and their count, in order of the count and then by order of the tokens. An obvious data structure for this would be a hashmap, like the one offered in C++'s STL, and then dump the values into a vector to sort. But neither of those are readily available in C.

I was thinking of doing an array of Pairs (structure), indexed by the ASCII value, and then sorting the array. Is there a better, more optimal choice? Is there something easier to implement than that? I'm very new to C, so I'm not used to the bare bones of it.

Comment: I'd just use `int counts[256];`.  That is, an ordinary array, indexed by ASCII character value.  Although, that's not adequate all by itself for your goal of sorting by character count while retaining character value.  For that, yes, an array of `struct {char charval; int count; }` might be just the ticket.

Comment: I second the array approach. But for more complex cases you can implement hashmap. See https://attractivechaos.wordpress.com/2009/09/29/khash-h/ for example.

Comment: I'm surprised I came up with that myself. Thanks for the validations, you two.

Comment: It seems as though you are going to take a simple array approach to your problem.  I just wanted to point out that (if you are using a posix compliant system), you do have access to a hashmap in case you end up needing it. There is [hsearch](https://linux.die.net/man/3/hsearch) and some non-standard gnu extensions that give it some more flexibility.

Comment: Easy enough to write a simple hash table. Or use a library that provides one.

Comment: This is in fact a histogram.

Answer (score 0):

As @JB-MSI already answered, you just need an array for the counting.
For the second part (sorting), you can use the C standard library function `qsort()` from `stdlib.h`.

In order to avoid global variables (the predicate function passed to `qsort` lacks a context parameter, as so many old functions in that old language),
you need to pack the character and its count into a struct, then sort by count. So it looks a bit more complicated than it actually is, grace to the enlightenment of the 1965 C-standard library designers.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define NCHARS 256

bool character_count(const char* str,
             size_t* frequencies,
             size_t nfrequencies) {
  if (NULL == frequencies)
    return false;
  if (nfrequencies < 256)
    return false;
  for (;*str != '\0'; str++) {
    frequencies[*str]++;
  }
  return true;
}

typedef struct CharCount_tag {
  char c;
  size_t count;
} CharCount_t;

int charcount_compare(const void* cc1, const void* cc2) {
  CharCount_t* c1 = (CharCount_t*)cc1;
  CharCount_t* c2 = (CharCount_t*)cc2;
  if (c1->count == c2->count)
    return 0;
  else if (c1->count > c2->count)
    return -1;
  else
    return 1;
}

int main (int argc, const char* argv[]) {
  if (argc > 1) {
    size_t frequencies[NCHARS];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < NCHARS; i++) {
      frequencies[i] = 0;
    }
    if (character_count(argv[1], frequencies, NCHARS)) {
      CharCount_t cc[NCHARS];
      for (size_t i = 0; i < NCHARS; i++) {
        cc[i].c = (char) i;
        cc[i].count = frequencies[i];
      }
      qsort(cc, NCHARS, sizeof(cc[0]), charcount_compare);
      for (size_t i = 0; i < NCHARS; i++) {
        printf("%d (%c) %zu\n", cc[i].c, cc[i].c, cc[i].count);
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's are two alternative versions. Obviously works by scanning a compile-time string. Easy to adapt this to scanning characters from an open file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *ASCIItbl =
    "NULSOHSTXETXEOTENQACKBELBS HT LF VT FF CR SO SI "
    "DLEDC1DC2DC3DC4NAKSYNETBCANEM SUBESCFS GS RS US "
    "SP  !  \"  #  $  %  &  '  (  )  *  +  ,  -  .  / "
    " 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  :  ;  <  =  >  ? "
    " @  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N  O "
    " P  Q  R  S  T  U  V  W  X  Y  Z  [  \\  ]  ^  _ "
    " `  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o "
    " p  q  r  s  t  u  v  w  x  y  z  {  |  }  ~ DEL";

char *smpl = "I wish I was\n\twhat I was\nwhen I wished I was\n\twhat I am now.\n";

int main() {
    printf( "%s\n", smpl );

    int i;
    size_t cnt[ 128 + 1 ]; // built for 7-bit ASCII

    memset( cnt, 0, sizeof cnt );

    int maxIND = 0; 
    for( char *cp = smpl; *cp; cp++ ) { // count while tracking most frequent
        cnt[ *cp ]++;
        if( cnt[ maxIND ] < cnt[ *cp ] )
            maxIND = cp - smpl;
    }
#if 1
    // output most frequent while scanning for next most freq
    printf( "Descending order of frequency:\n" );
    int nxtInd = 128;
    do {
        nxtInd = 128;
        for( i = 0; i < sizeof cnt/sizeof cnt[0]; i++ )
            if( cnt[ i ] == cnt[ maxIND ] )
                printf( "%4d %.3s\n", cnt[ maxIND ], &ASCIItbl[ 3*i ] );
            else if( cnt[ i ] && cnt[ i ] < cnt[ maxIND ] && cnt[ i ] > cnt[ nxtInd ] )
                nxtInd = i;
    } while( ( maxIND = nxtInd ) != 128 );

    // simple output of non-zero counts in ascending ASCII order
    printf( "Ascending order of ASCII value:\n" );
    for( i = 0; i < sizeof cnt/sizeof cnt[0] - 1; i++ )
        if( cnt[ i ]  )
            printf( "%4d %.3s\n", cnt[ i ], &ASCIItbl[ 3*i ] );
#else
    // Output side-by-side
    printf( "frequency       ASCII seqn\n" );
    int idx = 0, nxtInd = 128;
    do {
        nxtInd = 128;
        for( i = 0; i < sizeof cnt/sizeof cnt[0]; i++ )
            if( cnt[ i ] == cnt[ maxIND ] ) {
                printf( "%4d %.3s", cnt[ maxIND ], &ASCIItbl[ 3*i ] );
                while( !cnt[++idx] ) ;
                printf( "\t%4d %.3s\n", cnt[ idx ], &ASCIItbl[ 3*idx ] );
            } else if( cnt[ i ] && cnt[ i ] < cnt[ maxIND ] && cnt[ i ] > cnt[ nxtInd ] )
                nxtInd = i;
    } while( ( maxIND = nxtInd ) != 128 );
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

Output (from the upper version):

```
I wish I was
        what I was
when I wished I was
        what I am now.

Descending order of frequency:
  12 SP
   9  w
   6  I
   6  a
   5  h
   5  s
   4 LF
   2 HT
   2  e
   2  i
   2  n
   2  t
   1  .
   1  d
   1  m
   1  o
Ascending order of ASCII value:
   2 HT
   4 LF
  12 SP
   1  .
   6  I
   6  a
   1  d
   2  e
   5  h
   2  i
   1  m
   2  n
   1  o
   5  s
   2  t
   9  w
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are talking about an occurrence of characters? you can use a basic array.
(this is pure c ,ansi only but you can adjust as needed)

```
void countchar(const char * str, int &charcount[256])
{
    for (x = 0; x < strlen(str); c++)
    {
        if (isalpha(str[x])) // optional
          charcount[(int)str[x])]++;
    }
}
```

Assumes passed array is initialized!

Edit 1: // your basic sort functions

```
void swap(int* f, int* l)
{
    int temp = *f;
    *f = *l;
    *l = temp;
}

void sortcount(int &charcount[256])
{
    int i, j, min_idx;
    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        min_idx = i;
        for (j = i + 1; j < 256; j++)
            if (charcount[j] < charcount[min_idx])
                min_idx = j;
        swap(&charcount[min_idx], &charcount[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: To make the answer complete, you might want to address the second part of what the question wants to do: Sort by charcount.

Comment: With the `&` in the function signature... are you compiling this with a C++ compiler?

Comment: Good catch.  Hard to "back think" to pure c

Comment: Given the question, please edit to make it C rather than C++. If not, others may be justified in flagging as "not an answer."